# Changing buffer size on MediaPlayer(android)?

Tags: android, media-player, audio-streaming

Is there any way to change default buffer size on streaming MediaPlayer?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific? Which buffer size are you referring to?

Answer (score 1):

In standard android distribution, the input `DataSource` is cached through a `NuCachedSource2` implementation as seen [here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/AwesomePlayer.cpp#2034).

The `NuCachedSource2` is implemented through a page-cache mechanism with a lower and higher thresholds of 4 MB and 20 MB as shown [here](http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/av/media/libstagefright/include/NuCachedSource2.h#75).

I presume you could tweak these parameters, rebuild `libstagefright.so` and replace the same to test it in your system.